# Sharepoint Online REST Item call returning empty array

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, postman

I have a Sharepoint Online sitecollection `http://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test` and I have set up an app to be able to get the authentication tokens in Azure AD (Sites.FullControl.All for Sharepoint).

I set up Postman to test the API calls and I'm getting expected results when I call `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')`, so the authorization is working (token is also not expired). As expected I can see `"ItemCount": 1` among other information in the request.

However, when I want to list the items with `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items` I'm getting an empty array returned: `"results": []`. I then added app permissions to the sharepoint site with the following permissions (exactly this string):

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

I have also tried it with `/sitecollection/web/list` as the scope and then choosing `Documents` in the next step, it didn't work either.

Unfortunately, I'm still getting an empty array. What could be the error here? Did I forget to set something up?

Comment: You can check whether the item has independent permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding your permission like this.

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowOnAppPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

AllowOnAppPolicy lets SharePoint check the permissions of the add-in instead of on user level. ([More info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-authorization-policy-types-in-sharepoint))